# SQL Login not working but sign up is working

Tags: php, html, authentication, web

I have copied the login and sign up code from https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php.

Sign up works fine but login does not work.

For some reason, it looks like it can not get past the statement execution.

I do not get any PHP errors at all.

When I click submit, the page refreshes and nothing happens. It does not even redirect.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";
 echo $lin;
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);}?>
```

HTML FORM:

```
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post"> <!-- LOG IN form-->
                <input type="email" name="username" id="username" class="" placeholder="E-Mail">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
                <input style="background-color: #bdd6ff; border-color: #bdd6ff" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in."><br><br>

            </form>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything with the variables that might contain an error message. `$username_err ` and `$password_err` for example. Try echoing them.

Comment: Why 3 variables for ONE piece of data `$username` and `$param_username` and `$_POST["username"]` remember, memory may be cheap nowadays but there is no reason to waste it

Comment: And any tutorial that uses `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` instead of `$stmt->bind_param()` should be ignored

Comment: You started the session twice; *why?*

Comment: Tutorial to take a simple process and turn it into a nightmare

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.